# Equivalent to @Inject @Active of CDI in Spring

Tags: java, spring, cdi

with CDI, you can do something like this:

```
@Inject @Active
UserFactory userFactory;
```

The code means: I want an userFactory that returns only active users.

What is the equivalent way of Spring? I did my research but the nearest I found was Spring profiles. It looks like:

```
@Autowired @Profiles("active")
UserFactory userFactory;
```

The problem is only one profile can be actived at the same time, correct? If so, it looks more like @Alternative in CDI to me and it doesn't solve the problem I mentioned.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for @Qualifier

Comment: https://spring.io/blog/2014/11/04/a-quality-qualifier

Comment: What do you mean the userFactory should return only list of active users? Is the active field a column in some db? Or is it stored in memory in java runtime?

Comment: You can have as many active profiles you want. But you probably want to look into `@Qualifier` (which I suspect `@Active` is as well).

Comment: @yaswanth yes, that's the point. The interface is a factory. And UserFactory produces Users, of course. But there are many kind of users: active users, disabled users, blah blah. The Rest service doesn't care about how to get those users. The rest service doesn't care about which arguments should be passed in either. If I must write UserFactory.getFactory("active"), I will be unhappy. By using annotation, the Spring container will choose the implementation for me. Maybe it will choose new GetActiveUserFromDBFactory() or new GetActiveUserFromCache(). Who cares?

Comment: @M.Deinum yes, that seems pretty much like what I want. Thank you! Would you mind writing in the "answer section" so that I can choose it as the right answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring can also use qualifiers (defined with `@Qualifier`). Probably the `@Active` is already a `@Qualifier` and as such can be used to determine which one to use.

```
@Component
@Active
public ActiveUserFactory implements UserFactory { ... }
```

Then in the place you want to use this one add the `@Active` qualifier again.

```
@Autowired
@Active
private UserFactory userFactory;
```

If you don't want to create an annotation you could also use a plain `@Qualifer("active")` for instance.

For a more elaborate explanation you might want to check [the reference guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers).

Comment: Maybe @Qualifier( "active") is more correct way of Spring. I just want to add that.

Comment: No not really you can use `@Qualifier` to create qualifier annotations. This is also explained in the reference guide (I'll add the link to the documentation).